# Lock ASP.NET Control While Processing User Request

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

Let me dive into the problem directly:

There is an ASP.NET Submit Form (In this example just a mock one). I am going to lock the Page Web Controls and display some animated progress bar as soon as the user hits the "Submit" Button. I have tried the following code snippet **but the page controls are not lock!** And I need t handle it.

Here is the Markup:

```
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" ID="smgr" EnablePartialRendering="True"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <div>
        <asp:UpdateProgress runat="server" ID="ProgressDisplay" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdatePanelForm">
            <ProgressTemplate>
                <img src="Images/25-1.gif" />
            </ProgressTemplate>
        </asp:UpdateProgress>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanelForm">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtName"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtLName"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
                <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnSubmit" Text="Submit Form" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" />
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
</form>
```

And The Code Behind:

```
 protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write(string.Format("You have wrote: {0} {1} {2}", txtName.Text, " ", txtLName.Text));
    }
```

It works fine and the image displays. **But, the text boxes are not locked so that the user may change the their values which must not happened.**

So does anyone have any idea to handle this matter?

Thank you so much,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a `div` and place those controls in that div. when you need, make that div enable or disable. Don't forget to mention `runat=server` and name of the div

Comment: Yeah.. Thank you.. it works good. I also found a similar solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10682086/gray-out-the-webpage-during-update-progress-runs-in-asp-net